# Connection between Bluemix's Liberty for Java and Cloudant throw RuntimeError everyday

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, cloudant

I create an application by using Bluemix's Liberty for Java to connect Cloudant. I found RuntimeException everyday while connecting to my RESTful API. However, I have to restart my application everyday to solve this problem.

An error is shown as follow:

```
Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage:116'
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Error retrieving server response
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Error retrieving server response
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:163)
... 1 more
Caused by: com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: Error retrieving server response
at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.execute(CouchDbClient.java:501)
at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.executeToInputStream(CouchDbClient.java:515)
at com.cloudant.client.api.Database.findByIndex(Database.java:361)
at com.cloudant.client.api.Database.findByIndex(Database.java:321)
at th.co.gosoft.rest.TopicService.getHotTopicList(TopicService.java:82)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:636)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Server rejected operation
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.expect100Continue(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudant.http.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:231)
at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.execute(CouchDbClient.java:466)
... 9 more
```

I use this CloudantClientMgr as follow:

```
package th.co.gosoft.util;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import com.cloudant.client.api.ClientBuilder;
import com.cloudant.client.api.CloudantClient;
import com.cloudant.client.api.Database;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class CloudantClientMgr {

    private static CloudantClient cloudant = null;
    private static Database db = null;

    private static String databaseName = "go10_db";

    private static String url = "https://xxxxxxxxxx-bluemix.cloudant.com";
    private static String user = "xxxxxxxxxx-bluemix";
    private static String password = "password";

    private static void initClient() {
        if (cloudant == null) {
            synchronized (CloudantClientMgr.class) {
                if (cloudant != null) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    cloudant = createClient();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                System.out.println("cloudant : " + cloudant.serverVersion());

            }
        }
    }

    private static CloudantClient createClient() throws MalformedURLException {
        String VCAP_SERVICES = System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
        String serviceName = null;
        CloudantClient client;

        if (VCAP_SERVICES != null) {
            System.out.println("VCAP_SERVICE");
            JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(VCAP_SERVICES);
            Entry<String, JsonElement> dbEntry = null;
            Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = obj.entrySet();
            for (Entry<String, JsonElement> eachEntry : entries) {
                if (eachEntry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains("cloudant")) {
                    dbEntry = eachEntry;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (dbEntry == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not find cloudantNoSQLDB key in VCAP_SERVICES env variable");
            }

            obj = (JsonObject) ((JsonArray) dbEntry.getValue()).get(0);
            serviceName = (String) dbEntry.getKey();
            System.out.println("Service Name - " + serviceName);

            obj = (JsonObject) obj.get("credentials");

            user = obj.get("username").getAsString();
            password = obj.get("password").getAsString();

            client = ClientBuilder.account(user)
                    .username(user)
                    .password(password)
                    .build();

        } else {
            System.out.println("LOCAL");
            client = ClientBuilder.url(new URL(url))
                    .username(user)
                    .password(password)
                    .build();
        }

        return client;

    }

    public static Database getDB() {
        if (cloudant == null) {
            initClient();
        }

        if (db == null) {
            try {
                db = cloudant.database(databaseName, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("DB Not found", e);
            }
        }
        return db;
    }

    private CloudantClientMgr() {
    }
}
```

I use this code to connect CloudantClientMgr as follow:

```
@Path("topic")
public class TopicService {

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public Response createTopic(TopicModel topicModel) {

        Database db = CloudantClientMgr.getDB();

        com.cloudant.client.api.model.Response response = db.save(topicModel);

        String result = response.getId();

        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

The Cloudant version is 2.4.2

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId>
  <artifactId>cloudant-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If anyone used to found this problem, please let me know the better solution than  I have to restart my application every day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe sounds identical to one that was resolved in [version 2.4.1](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/releases/tag/2.4.1).

I would check to make sure you don't have multiple versions of the cloudant-client included in your application or classpath and that your application is really using version 2.4.2. The line numbers in the stack trace you provide do not match with the source for 2.4.2.